# Next object instance IGListKit

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionreusableview, iglistkit

Edit: I am new to the field, I did not get a response. Can anyone tell me if I am missing some information? or how I could improve it?

I want an instance from the **next object** to set a Label text in my current cell
 cell.Label.text = talents(nextIndex).name //<- Something of this sort

**Tried**: passing array input to SectionController to use as
talents[index+1]
**Error**: File out of range

My Section Controller

```
class SectionController: ListSectionController {

    var talents: Talent!
    weak var delegate: SectionControllerDelegate?

}

extension SectionController {

    override func sizeForItem(at index: Int) -> CGSize {
        guard
            let context = collectionContext
            else {
                return .zero
        }
        let width = context.containerSize.width
        let height = context.containerSize.height
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }

    override func cellForItem(at index: Int) -> UICollectionViewCell {    

        guard let cell = collectionContext?.dequeueReusableCellFromStoryboard(withIdentifier: "HomeCell",
                                                                              for: self,
                                                                              at: index) as? HomeCell else {
                                                                                fatalError()
        }

        cell.nameLabel.text = talents.name
        cell.descView.text = talents.largeDesc
        cell.shortDesc.text = talents.smallDesc 

//        let nextTalent = talents[index+1]
//        cell.nextIntroFunc(nextlabels: nextTalent)

        return cell
    }

    override func didUpdate(to object: Any) {
        talents = object as? Talent
    }

}
```

My ListAdapterDataSource

```
extension Home: ListAdapterDataSource {

  func objects(for listAdapter: ListAdapter) -> [ListDiffable] {
    print(talents)
    return talents
  }


  func listAdapter(_ listAdapter: ListAdapter, sectionControllerFor object: Any)
  -> ListSectionController {
    return SectionController()
  }

  func emptyView(for listAdapter: ListAdapter) -> UIView? {
    print("emptyView")
    return nil
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`talents` in the section controller isn't an array. It's just a single `Talent`, so calling `[index + 1]` on it is going to throw an error. (You might want to rename the property of the model in the section controller to `talent` so it's less confusing.)

Best practice for ListSectionController is to keep a 1:1 relationship between your object model and the section controller. If you want to have reference to the next object, you could create a cell/view model layer based on `talent` that includes reference to the next talent as well.

For example:

```html
class TalentSectionModel: ListDiffable {
    let talent: Talent
    let nextTalent: Talent?
   
    init(_ talent: Talent, nextTalent: Talent?) {
        self.talent = talent
        self.nextTalent = nextTalent
    }
    
    // whatever properties you want to expose
  
    var name: String {
        return talent.name
    }
   
    // example of exposing info about next talent
    var nextTalentName: String? {
      return nextTalent?.name
    }
  
    // ListDiffable protocol
    // make sure to implement these two so diffing works
    func diffIdentifier() -> NSObjectProtocol {}
    func isEqual(toDiffableObject object: ListDiffable?) -> Bool {}
}
```

You could also just only pass in the necessary properties from the next talent without passing in the entire `nextTalent` if you don't want the section model to store the entire object.

Now with the `TalentSectionModel` you would map over your talents array in `Home` and return an array of view models in `objects()` under `ListAdapterDataSource`. Then, in your section controller you'll have the next talent's information available to you through the view model.

Resources:
[ListKit Modeling and Binding](https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit/blob/master/Guides/Modeling%20and%20Binding.md) (talks about the ListBindingSectionController, but also helpful to read for general understanding of model and section controller relationship),
[ListKit best practices](https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit/blob/master/Guides/Best%20Practices%20and%20FAQ.md)